# Angular2 display base64 image ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: angular

In my template:

```
<h5>Image upload</h5>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="changeListener($event)">
<div *ngIf="image">
    <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,' +image | safeHtml">
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
image: string='';

changeListener($event) : void {
    this.readThis($event.target);
}

readThis(inputValue: any): void {

    var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
    var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();

    myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        this.image = myReader.result;
        console.log(this.image)
    }
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

safeHtml is a pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(html);
  }
}
```

However, after image is uploaded I get `ERR_INVALID_URL` error. I can see the base64 string in my developer console though. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result from `myReader.result` already contains the `'data:image/jpg;base64,'` string, so you should remove that:

```
<img [src]="image | safeHtml">
```